# Using a USB Bluetooth dongle on Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, bluetooth

I recently purchased the Techkey Bluetooth dongle since I know the Pi system is unable to connect to multiple Bluetooth devices simultaneously. Unfortunately, I haven't had any luck doing so. I got Bluetooth to work on the Pi4, but it isn't using the dongle to do so. So I was wondering how I can go about doing this? Maybe there is some hidden gem article I missed or something. The 'solution' I tried implementing is as follows:

1. Edit the config file by plugging the Pi SD card into your PC and adding "dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt" to the end of it
2. Boot the Pi back up and plug in the dongle
3. Next, you execute the following command into the terminal: 'sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bluetooth'
4. Finally, check the status of your work by typing in 'sudo service bluetooth status'

P.S. Any suggestions would be truly appreciated, thanks :)

Output of 'bluetoothctl list' command:
[image]

Bluetooth Dongle: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07J5WFPXX?tag=romanceun-20&linkCode=osi&th=1&psc=1&keywords=Raspberry%20Pi%20Bluetooth%20Dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07J5WFPXX)

Update: I ordered the Panda Bluetooth 4.0 USB Nano Adapter. So I hope that works because I have just been twiddling my thumbs.

Comment: `nonapplicable since they're for the Pi3` ... why do you believe that the issue is related to the Raspberry Pi, and not related to linux

Comment: how are we to know that you have not already tried any suggestions anyone makes? ... `read countless articles and watched multiple videos` does not describe what you actually tried

Comment: Okay sorry, I guess I should have listed the 'solution' I found online. What you're suppost to do apparently, is edit the config file by plugging the Pi SD card into your PC and adding "dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt" to the end of it. Boot the Pi back up and plug in the dongle. Next, you execute the following command into the terminal: 'sudo apt-get install  --no-install-recommends bluetooth'. Finally, check the status of your work by typing in 'sudo service bluetooth status'.

Comment: Did the solution you outlined in the comment above work? If not please update your question with that as an example of what you have tried.  Can you also try the following command and post the result in the question: `bluetoothctl list`. Do you see your new Bluetooth dongle in the list?

Comment: Okay done. And no I didn't see my Bluetooth dongle in the list, unfortunately.

Comment: Whenever I enter the 'lsusb' command my new Panda Bluetooth Dongle appears. However, I'm still having no success overriding the built-in Pi4 Bluetooth system.

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. I'm not sure what else to try. Does anyone have any further suggestions?